# Suppress page numbers but keep pagination

Tags: page-numbering, blank-page

I'm formatting a book. I want

- Title page (with no page number displayed on it)
- Copyright page  (with no page number displayed on it)
- Fancier title  (with no page number displayed on it)
- blank page  (with no page number displayed on it)
- introduction (displaying an odd page number, any number, any style)

I have tried this:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}

\begin{document}

\title{Pagination troubles}
\author{Frustration}
\vskip 10cm
\date{2020}

\frontmatter
\maketitle

\pagebreak

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
Published in 2020


copyright \copyright 2020

\vskip 3cm

ISBN 000-0-00000000-0

\end{center}

\pagebreak

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}

\Large{Fancy Title}

\LARGE{Pagination Troubles}

\Large{Subtitle}

Publshing House

\end{center}

\pagebreak
%\pagebreak - LaTeX ignores this second \pagebreak, if present.

% by default, LaTeX puts a blank page in here, which is nice, but it
% has a Roman page number on it (iv). 

%\pagenumbering{arabic} -- LaTeX creates no blank page, and puts
% chapter one on the next (fourth) page, so therefore all
% odd pages are on the left page, and all even pages on the right
% i.e. the reverse of how it should be

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

%\pagenumbering{arabic} -- if put here, LaTeX ignores it and
% puts in a blank page displaying the number'iv', and the next 
% page is numbered 'v', i.e. the default behaviour

\chapter{Introduction}\label{introduction}

ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute 
irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 
mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

Do you have a better suggestion, i.e. one that works?

(I also have tried `\pagenumbering{gobble}` instead of 
`\thispagestyle{empty}`, but that produces the same
results.)

Thanks for your time and input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most important, you need a `\mainmatter` to switch to the arabic  numeration in the Introduction page. Then the header will be numbered as "Chapter 1". Use `\chapter*{}` if you want just see "Introduction".

Then  add `\thispagestyle{empty}` in back pages  (in title pages is not needed).

On the other hand, note  that `\Large` command have not arguments, so you should not use `\Large{foo}` but `{\Large foo}` to limit the scope of this command.

All together, it could be something like:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\title{Pagination troubles}
\author{Frustration}
\date{2020}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Published in 2020\par
copyright \copyright 2020
\vskip 3cm
ISBN 000-0-00000000-0
\end{center}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
{\Large Fancy Title}\par
{\LARGE Pagination Troubles}\par
{\Large Subtitle}\par
Publishing House
\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mainmatter
\chapter*{Introduction}\label{introduction}
Lore ipsum ...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Fran, that was very helpful.

What I did in the end was use `\newpage` 
 instead of  `\pagebreak`. And then explicitly state where the blank pages of the front matter need to be.

```
\frontmatter
\maketitle


\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
Published by Publishing House 

\vskip 3cm


copyright \copyright 2020

\vskip 3cm

ISBN NUMBER

\end{center}


\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}

\Large{Author}

\vskip 3cm

\LARGE{Title}

\Large{Subtitle}

\vskip 10cm

Publising House

\end{center}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vskip 0cm

\newpage

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\chapter{Author's Foreword}\label{foreword}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified, and simplified, your MWE.

```
% pagenumprob.tex  SE 547243

\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} % PW added

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % PW added

\title{Pagination troubles}
\author{Frustration}
\vskip 10cm
\date{2020}

\frontmatter
\maketitle

%\pagebreak            % PW commented out 
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
Published in 2020

copyright \copyright 2020

\vskip 3cm

ISBN 000-0-00000000-0

\end{center}

%\pagebreak              % PW changed
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\begin{center}

\Large{Fancy Title}

\LARGE{Pagination Troubles}

\Large{Subtitle}

Publshing House

\end{center}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\mainmatter         % PW added
\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{Introduction}\label{introduction}

ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute 
irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 
mollit anim id est laborum.

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

The `\pagestyle{empty}` macro applies to all following pages (thus no need for all the `\thispagestyle{empty}` commands). After `\maketitle` a new page is started so no need for `\pagebreak`. Anyway, I prefer `\clearpage` to `\pagebreak` in general. The `\mainmatter` command sets arabic page numbers and by default chapters in `book` start on righthand pages. I had to remember to switch from `\pagestyle{empty}` to something that showed page numbers, hence the  `\makepagestyle{plain}`.